# Correcting python code for using functions

Tags: python, regex, list, function, regex-group

So huge disclaimer first: I am very new to python and programing in general, and this is my first time using functions. I would be very glad for any help, but the end goal here is not to have the prettiest or the most efficient code. I just want it to somehow work.

I have written the program below but I can't get it to work properly.

Because this is a graded exercise for Uni I have certain restrictions that I am supposed to follow:

This is my code:

```
import re
import sys
# get the filename
filename = sys.argv[1]

# open a file for reading
infile = open(filename, 'r')


########################################################################################
# function to return just the consonants in a given namecdef get_consonants(y):
def get_consonants(y):
    only_consonants_sep = re.findall('[^\W_aeiou]', y)
    only_consonants = ''.join(only_consonants_sep)
    return only_consonants


########################################################################################
# function to return first and last name according to all rules
def parse_name(input_y):
        
    # Parse the names to first (meaning first+middle, if it exists) and last names
    for element in input_y:
    
        # define last name for later use
        last_namegroup = re.search('(\w*)\t', element)
        last_name = last_namegroup.group(1)
        
        # define what the middle name is for later use
        middle_namegroup = re.search('\s(\w)', element)
        middle_name = middle_namegroup.group(1)
        
        # define what first name is for later use
        first_namegroup = re.search('^(\S*)', element)
        first_name1 = first_namegroup.group(1) 
            
        
                # if length of consonant_first_middle is still larger than 8
                # take the consonants of only the first name
                # and add the first letter of the middle name defined above 
                if len(consonant_first_middle) > 8:
                    consonant_first_name = get_consonants(first_name1)
                    first_name = (f'{consonant_first_name}{middle_name}')
        
        # if there is no middle name, i.e. only ones white space in the line
        # then just take the word until the space and store it as first_name
        else:
            first_namegroup = re.search('^(\S*)', element)
            first_name = first_namegroup.group(1)   
        
                    
    return(first_name, last_name)
    

########################################################################################
# creating the email addresses
def create_email_address(first_name, last_name):
    
    for lines in infile:
        if re.search('\tstu', lines):
            domain = (f'{first_name}.{last_name}@uzh.ch')
        else:
            domain_part = re.search('\t(.*)$',lines)
            domain = (f'{first_name}.{last_name}@{domain_part.group(1)}.uzh.ch')
    return domain

########################################################################################
# function as the "top level" of the program that calls all other functions as needed.

def main():
  
    ####### Receive a file name from the command line
    # get the filename
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    # open a file for reading
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    
    ####### Normalise the input
    input_normalized = normalize(infile)
    
    ####### Parse the names as needed
    input_first, input_last = parse_name(input_normalized)
    
    ####### Create email addresses
    email_output = create_email_address(input_first, input_last)
    
    ####### Print the result
    for line in infile:
        print(f'{line} --> {email_output}')

main_function = main()
print(main_function)


As you can see, I think I did somethinf wrong with how the file is iterating through my code, but I simply can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

I appreciate everything you could point out to me!
```

Comment: Your `normalize()` function is `return`ing inside the loop, that is it returns after the first loop iteration. And inside it, if it ran many loops, `line_list = []` would reset to an empty list every time through the loop.

Comment: In `create_email_address` the loop `for lines in infile:` shouldn't really be referencing `infile` which exists outside the function, and the loop is doing the same thing - resetting `domain =` over and over, then after doing that it returns (once) only the last `domain`.

Comment: You seem to have removed the information you are referring to with "As you can see, ...". I have undone that. If you need to edit your question please make sure that it stays anwerable and that it does not invalidate existing answers.

Comment: Okay @Yunnosch , I understand that.

Comment: Note that your code in the question should not be a plagiarism problem for Uni, it is your code after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my first answer, I tried not to change too much code, but I think it will be easier to re-think the logic, and rewrite the code. Here's what I came up with, I think this does what you need?

```
import sys, re


def normalize(name):
    name = name.lower()
    name = re.sub('ä', 'ae', name)
    name = re.sub('ü', 'ue', name)
    name = re.sub('ö', 'oe', name)
    name = re.sub('é|ë', 'e', name)
    return name


def remove_vowels(name):
    return re.sub('a|e|i|o|u', '', name)
    

def main(filename):
    # a list to store our output
    people = []

    # let's loop through each line, looking at
    # just one person at a time
    for line in open(filename, "r"):
        # remove trailing \n from each line
        line = re.sub("\n", "", line)

        # separate the name and domain
        name, domain = re.split("\t", line)

        # remove the accents and capitals
        normalized_name = normalize(name)

        # separate the name
        # we use a "*" so that the first and last names
        # are selected correctly, and then any remaining
        # characters in between are put into the middle name.
        first_name, *middle_name, last_name  = re.split(" ", normalized_name)
        middle_name = "".join(middle_name)

        full_first_name = first_name + middle_name

        # this is where we check for how
        # long the first and middle names are
        if len(full_first_name) > 8:
            full_first_name = remove_vowels(full_first_name)

            # now we check if this is still too long
            if len(full_first_name) > 8:
                full_first_name = remove_vowels(first_name)

                # check if they actually have a middle name
                if middle_name:
                    full_first_name += middle_name[0]
        
        # now let's grab the domain
        subdomain = ""
        if domain != "stu":
            subdomain = domain + "."
        
        host = subdomain + "uzh.ch"

        
        # now let's format this into an address
        address = f"{full_first_name}.{last_name}@{host}"

        people.append((name, address))

    return people



filename = sys.argv[1]
people = main(filename)

for name, address in people:
    print(name, "-->", address)
```

Output:

```
Raphael Fritz Bernasconi --> rphlfrtz.bernasconi@uzh.ch
Frédéric Piero --> frederic.piero@cl.uzh.ch
Sören Thaddäus Favre --> srnthdds.favre@uzh.ch
Regula Aegerter --> regula.aegerter@uzh.ch
Noël Äbiger --> noel.aebiger@cl.uzh.ch
Inés Desirée Muff --> nsdsr.muff@rom.uzh.ch
Sébastien Merian --> sbstn.merian@uzh.ch
Liam Cereghetti --> liam.cereghetti@uzh.ch
Björn Michael Crivelli --> bjrnmchl.crivelli@ds.uzh.ch
Joëlle Fürrer --> joelle.fuerrer@uzh.ch
```

Hopefully the comments in the code do a good job of explaining what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much. That already helped quite a bit!!
Now, it seems that two of the criteria I have to fulfill still don't quite work:
- if the the first and the middle names exceed 8 characters, only the consonants should be used for them.
- If this shortened variant of first and middle name still exceeds 8 characters, only use the first letter of the middle name (even if it is a vowel), e.g. Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart mus → wlfgnga.mozart@mus.uzh.ch.
While this is in the code, it doesn't seem to work for the output...

Comment: This works very well:) Thank you so much for your help and explanations!

Comment: Hey, I know this is a really stupid question to ask, but I think I made a mistake... I talked to the people who are grading our stuff and they mentioned that asking things on StackOverflow is considered plagiarism. Now, I know that you have put a lot of work into this code but I wanted to ask you if it were at all possible for you to delete your answer. I am extremely sorry to have to ask this of you but I simply didn't think about this. If you really don't want to do it, maybe it is possible to delete the output. At least then, they are less likely to find the code since I changed it a lot.

Comment: Deleting the answer does not help. It stays visible then, at least to users with a certain level of reputation, which the graders are sure to have. Also it stay plagiarism if you use it, even if it were not visible here. Because plagiarism is about what you do and not about what the grading people find out. The visibility problem you could tackle by flagging your own question and asking moderators to help with visibility. But you would have to convince them and "I want this invisible, so my plagiarising will not be detected" is probably not a convincing argument.

Comment: I recommend to talk to the grading people again and ask for a new assignment, which you then have to solve without asking here. That is the only way to avoid plagiarism I can think of, because you seem to already have ruled out the idea to solve your assignment on your own and noticably differently.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have worded it the best. Yes, I did use the code to solve my problems, but it is not the same anymore. I used its structure to rewrite my old one because I was more interested in learning something than just copy-pasting, i.e. plagiarism. But I get what you mean... after thinking about it and hearing what the instructors said it did not feel right to use the code. Which is why I am asking this. But it is also not my code. So I am aware that I would have to live with the consequences if Ed Ward decided to leave it.

Comment: If you have learned from this answer, but do not use the code shown here and do note the input you got here in your paper then I do not think that you are going to have trouble with plagiarism blames. Your code is probably still similar to the code in the quesiton, but that is your code, i.e. not plagiarism. You might have to prove to the graders that this is your account, but that should not be hard.

Comment: Okay, that is true... I just wanted to be completely save, that is why I asked. I did not do this out of malice. I just got really stressed and overwhelmed so I thought I would ask.

Comment: @zara.b: please do not ask again. Once posted, question and answer information should remain since they are not here for your benefit but for the benefit of future visitors with similar questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, I understand. I won’t.